# como usar el valor de una variable php como condicionante de un if

Tags: php

Tengo una variable en *PHP* que se rellena al recorrer la base de datos por lo cual es dinámica y tiene el texto de una condicionante de un `if`, pero no me funciona usándola dentro de un `if` ya que la reconoce como variable y no como el texto

dejo un ejemplo

```
$cadena = substr($cadena , 0, -2);

while ($filaLJ=pg_fetch_array($tabla_smsLJ)){            

        if($resultadoLJ=='' || $cadena ){
            $vvv=1;
        }else{
            
                print_r("INSERT INTO SMS VALUES(DEFAULT,'569".$filaLJ[0]."','".$resultadoLJ."','$fecha_reg','','')");
                
        }
    }
```

la variable `$cadena` está compuesta del siguiente texto dinámico

```
($filaLJ["esp_desc"]=="'.$hg.'" && $filaLJ["doc_rut"]=="'.$rutmed.'") ||
```

Comment: ¿Por qué poner las condiciones como cadena y no como código normal? Tal vez podría funcionar con `eval($cadena)`, pero no tiene sentido.

Answer (score 1):

Estás realizando mal el IF

```
if($resultadoLJ=='' || $cadena ){......}
```

Debe ser de este modo

```
if($resultadoLJ == '' || $resultado == $cadena ){......}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera que tienes de comparar `strings` en `PHP` es utilizar el método [strcmp()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strcmp.php)

```
if (strcmp($resultado, "") == 0 || strcmp($resultado, $cadena) == 0)){
    ...
}
```